# How to encode complex time step data into a single vector for input into a RNN?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm working on a predictive TensorFlow RNN for music visualization, similar to the one seen [here](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/) for characters. For example, in a standard character RNN, my understanding is that each character is encoded as a sparse 26-long vector. If I were to do something similar with a 80x80 greyscale image, I would be inclined to convert it to a 6400 wide vector.

However, in my situation, in each timestep, the network must decide on the coordinates of the object as well as its color (classification) and some other classification properties with varying numbers of options.

For example, a single data point might look like this:

```
[257 (1-500), 97 (1-400), 6 (1-9), 1 (0-1)]
```

I could conceivably turn this data into a single vector (4 one-hot vectors concatenated) and then run softmax over various intervals, but this seems inefficient, and I would need to implement a custom softmax (not the end of the world...).

I could also potentially encode the coordinates as floats instead of sparse vectors and concatenate them to the other sparse vectors before calculating the cross entropy of the whole set.

```
[0.514, .97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

However, I'm worried that this will undervalue the importance of the coordinates, seeing as they only represent two data points versus the 11 of the classification segment.

Are there better (built in?) ways to represent data like this?